# Script apenas número

Tags: php, javascript, mysql

Tenho um script que só permite digitar números em um `input` porém quando eu digito um número de telefone e salvo no banco de dados. O número é salvo todo embaralhado. Exemplo:

Digito no `input` 27998439197 e no banco ele salva como 2147483647.

Código:

```js
function SomenteNumero(e){
    var tecla=(window.event)?event.keyCode:e.which;   
    if((tecla>47 && tecla<58))
      return true;
    else{
     if (tecla==8 || tecla==0) 
        return true;
     else 
        return false;
    }
}
```

```html
<input type="text" name="numero" class="form-control"
     id="exampleInputEmail1" maxlength="11"
     onkeypress='return SomenteNumero(event)' required />
```

**PHP** que insere no banco:

```html
<?php
session_start();

//apartir daqui faz o cadastro do usuario ao clicar no botão cadastrar que receber o nome de btnCadastrar
$btnCadastrar = filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'salvar', FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);
if($btnCadastrar){
include_once ("../conn/conexao.php");
$dados = filter_input_array(INPUT_POST, FILTER_DEFAULT);
//aqui insere os dados na tb_usuario
$result_usuario = "INSERT INTO tb_numeros(numero, funcionario, rca, regiao, nchip, imei)VALUES(
 '".$dados['numero']."',
 '".$dados['funcionario']."',
 '".$dados['rca']."',
 '".$dados['regiao']."',
 '".$dados['nchip']."',
 '".$dados['imei']."'
 )";
 $mensagem="<script>
   alert('Numero ja cadastrado.');
   window.location='index.php';
  </script>";
$resultado_usuario = mysqli_query($conexao, $result_usuario) or die ($mensagem);
if($resultado_usuario):
 echo "<script>
   alert('Cadastrado Com Sucesso.');
   window.location='index.php';
  </script>"; 
else:
 echo "<script>
   alert('Ocorreu um erro ao cadastrar, entre em contato com o administrador.');
   window.location='index.php';
  </script>";
endif;
}

?>
```

Comment: O problema parece ser no php;

Comment: pronto @rray editado

Comment: pronto @CaiqueRomero editado

Comment: Número é um varchar no banco de dados?

Comment: @rray número e int (11)

Comment: Se é um telefone deveria ser um varchar.

Comment: eu só deixo ele digitar número por isso coloquei int, entende? na vai ter caracteres

Comment: Você chegou a fazer um `die($result_usuario);` para ver o que está como é formado seu insert?

Comment: Ferb o int não permite zero a esquerda imagina que vai salvar um 0800 da vida, ai seu campo não vai te atender.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Voce atingiu o valor máximo suportado pelo tipo **int** no banco, tente trocar por um tipo **bigint** (se quiser mesmo manter como valor desse tipo, eu colocaria um **varchar**)

Veja os limites dos [tipos de data númericos](https://docs.microsoft.com/pt-br/sql/t-sql/data-types/int-bigint-smallint-and-tinyint-transact-sql) na imagem:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]